# Passive to active voice NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am in a need of converting a passive sentence to active sentence. Using stanford NLP parser, I came to know that I can detect active/passive voice. Can somebody throw some light on whether we can do this? If so, would be much helpful if some examples/link is provided.

1) what I am trying is feasible or not? I don't want to spend time on something that can't be achievable
2) If it is feasible, can the NLP parsers help? Am I looking in the right direction?
3) If not, what are the tools/techniques that can help me in achieving this?
4) So far, I am able to identify whether a sentence is in passive voice/active voice, subject, object.

Answer (score 1):

Update: 
There are some [hacky ways](https://github.com/rgrishman/jet/blob/52ca610354b9e76d954e62725e0fb56762e674d1/src/main/java/edu/nyu/jet/parser/DepTransformer.java#L233-L260) of doing this; not sure how good is the quality.

---

Use this [feature extractor in Edison](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/blob/d62d0fd14f928263cc5a61385394a7a07d529c62/edison/src/main/java/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/edison/features/factory/VerbVoiceIndicator.java). It uses the parse tree to decide whether the voice is active or passive.

Comment: But that's only the first step towards changing it.

Comment: oops. misunderstood. updated.

Comment: Thanks. Will try [link](https://github.com/rgrishman/jet/blob/52ca610354b9e76d954e62725e0fb56762e674d1/src/main/java/edu/nyu/jet/parser/DepTransformer.java#L233-L260)